# Linux Visual Code 'no space left on device'

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

I am running Linux Mint 21.1, and I am running VSCode with PlatformIO extension. My project folder is located on my server which I access with Samba. This setup works fine on Windows, with one registry change.

Whenever I try to compile code, I get an error:

```
Compiling .pio/build/ESP32/lib1d9/WiFi/WiFiSTA.cpp.o
/tmp/ccE4gY8E.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccE4gY8E.s:3187: Fatal error: can't write 4 bytes to section .literal._ZN11EEPROMClassC2Ev of .pio/build/ESP32/libed2/EEPROM/EEPROM.cpp.o: 'Operation not supported'
/tmp/ccE4gY8E.s:3187: Fatal error: can't close .pio/build/ESP32/libed2/EEPROM/EEPROM.cpp.o: No space left on device
*** [.pio/build/ESP32/libed2/EEPROM/EEPROM.cpp.o] Error 1
/tmp/cczanPYc.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cczanPYc.s:292: Fatal error: can't write 4 bytes to section .literal._ZN9WiFiClass9printDiagER5Print of .pio/build/ESP32/lib1d9/WiFi/WiFi.cpp.o: 'Operation not supported'
/tmp/cczanPYc.s:292: Fatal error: can't close .pio/build/ESP32/lib1d9/WiFi/WiFi.cpp.o: No space left on device
*** [.pio/build/ESP32/lib1d9/WiFi/WiFi.cpp.o] Error 1
/tmp/cc6b9P0Z.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cc6b9P0Z.s:1674: Fatal error: can't write 4 bytes to section .literal._Z18wifi_softap_configP13wifi_config_tPKcS2_h16wifi_auth_mode_thhbt of .pio/build/ESP32/lib1d9/WiFi/WiFiAP.cpp.o: 'Operation not supported'
/tmp/cc6b9P0Z.s:1674: Fatal error: can't close .pio/build/ESP32/lib1d9/WiFi/WiFiAP.cpp.o: No space left on device
*** [.pio/build/ESP32/lib1d9/WiFi/WiFiAP.cpp.o] Error 1
/tmp/cc5AEBw4.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cc5AEBw4.s:1583: Fatal error: can't write 4 bytes to section .literal._ZN9WiFiMultiD2Ev of .pio/build/ESP32/lib1d9/WiFi/WiFiMulti.cpp.o: 'Operation not supported'
/tmp/cc5AEBw4.s:1583: Fatal error: can't close .pio/build/ESP32/lib1d9/WiFi/WiFiMulti.cpp.o: No space left on device
*** [.pio/build/ESP32/lib1d9/WiFi/WiFiMulti.cpp.o] Error 1
/tmp/ccPCAQ20.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccPCAQ20.s:5420: Fatal error: can't write 4 bytes to section .literal._ZN10WiFiClient7connectE9IPAddresst of .pio/build/ESP32/lib1d9/WiFi/WiFiClient.cpp.o: 'No space left on device'
/home/rj/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/as: BFD (crosstool-NG esp-2021r2-patch5) 2.35.1.20201223 assertion fail /builds/idf/crosstool-NG/.build/xtensa-esp32-elf/src/binutils/bfd/elf.c:3163
```

The server should have plenty of space, as should my laptop. I am not really sure what directory it says lacks space, or how to solve the problem. I am also somewhat inexperienced with Linux, and coding in general. Any suggestions to how I might solve this?

---

Output of `df -k`
No drive over 75% use, terminal output:

```
rj@rj-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-9:~$ df -k 
Filesystem      1K-blocks  Used       Available Use% Mounted on   
tmpfs           3258932    3804       3255128   1%   /run
/dev/nvme0n1p4  117670808  19689764   91957520  18%  /
tmpfs           16294652   635664     15658988  4%   /dev/shm
tmpfs           5120       4          5116      1%   /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p1  262144     39600      222544    16%  /boot/efi
tmpfs           3258928    1676       3257252   1%   /run/user/1000
/dev/nvme0n1p3  377632764  281552012  96080752  75%  /media/rj/Windows
```

Comment: What is the result of `df -k` command?

Comment: No drive over 75% use, terminal output: rj@rj-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-9:~$ df -k
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs            3258932      3804   3255128   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p4 117670808  19689764  91957520  18% /
tmpfs           16294652    635664  15658988   4% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p1    262144     39600    222544  16% /boot/efi
tmpfs            3258928      1676   3257252   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/nvme0n1p3 377632764 281552012  96080752  75% /media/rj/Windows

Comment: Add this to the question, not in comments

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. You state _My project folder is located on my server which I access with Samba_: do you have the rights to write in that folder (and in the folder you are trying to compile into)?  As the user that is compiling the program try to create there a new file or to copy one... Note that some compiling options try to install the program in system directory (warning! and need of admninistrator's right: `sudo`). Again don't use `root` powers if you don't have complete control over what you are doing. Feel you feel free to [edit] your own post.

Comment: ps> From a terminal shell, you can `cd` into that directory (-ies) and ask there `df -h .`. Note the `.` that means here.

Comment: which filesystem are you using? If it's Btrfs then see [Ubuntu thinks Btrfs disk is full but it's not](https://askubuntu.com/q/464074/253474), [Btrfs out of space, but OS reports lots of disk space free](https://askubuntu.com/q/952171/253474)

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, sorry I couldnt reply yesterday. I tried 'df -h .' in the project folder on the server, it returns 79% of disk is used. The terminal says filesystem is gvfsd-fuse. I moved the project folder to a local path, worked as it should. Checked permissions on the server which is restricted. I can't change any permission on /run/user/1000/gvfs/ or below. Weird this wasn't a problem on Ubuntu.